# Sort array of maps using keys matching a value GO

Tags: arrays, sorting, go, maps

I have just started programming in Golang and want to sort an array of maps. I have an array of maps. Let's call it example_array.

```
example_array = [
  [
    { Name: "A", Value: 100 }, 
    { Name: "B", Value: 60 }, 
    { Name: "C", Value: 170 }, 
    { Name: "D", Value: 120} 
  ], 
  [
    { Name: "A", Value: 64 }, 
    { Name: "B", Value: 90 }, 
    { Name: "C", Value: 52 }, 
    { Name: "D", Value: 98} 
  ], 
  [
    { Name: "A", Value: 154 }, 
    { Name: "B", Value: 190 }, 
    { Name: "C", Value: 179 }, 
    { Name: "D", Value: 67 } 
  ]
```

]

Now I want to sort this array using value of key `"C"` so the example_array should be modified to ->

```
[
[{Name: "A", Value: 64}, {Name: "B", Value: 90}, {Name: "C", Value: 52}, {Name: "D", Value: 98}],
[{Name: "A", Value: 100}, {Name: "B", Value: 60}, {Name: "C", Value: 170}, {Name: "D", Value: 120}], 
[{Name: "A", Value: 154}, {Name: "B", Value: 190}, {Name: "C", Value: 179}, {Name: "D", Value: 67}]
]
```

If I sort the original array using value of key `"D"`, the original array should be modified to ->

```
[
[{Name: "A", Value: 154}, {Name: "B", Value: 190}, {Name: "C", Value: 179}, {Name: "D", Value: 67}],
[{Name: "A", Value: 64}, {Name: "B", Value: 90}, {Name: "C", Value: 52}, {Name: "D", Value: 98}]
[{Name: "A", Value: 100}, {Name: "B", Value: 60}, {Name: "C", Value: 170}, {Name: "D", Value: 120}]
]
```

How can I sort these array of maps in Golang. Please help!

Comment: Learn to use the [`sort`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/) package.  In addition to the package documentation, there are a lot of examples and explanations online for you to read.

Comment: @jrefior I have already checked the sort package but couldnt find an appropriate solution for this. Please help!

Comment: Then you might not understand the power of sort.Sort yet.  For example, do you understand the [Wrapper Example](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example__sortWrapper) in the package documentation?

Comment: Or perhaps you're not really trying to sort an array of maps.  The structure of your code excerpts is not completely clear as to data structure.  You could improve your question by posting a [`MCVE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: While you say you want to sort an array of maps, the operations you describe look more like sorting an array of arrays of maps.  Are those arrays in an array, or are they in something else?

Comment: @jrefior I have made my example more clear and you are right here I am trying to sort array of array of maps using value of a particular key in each array. Hope its more clear now. Please help!

Comment: That is a little clearer.  And are these `map[string]int` maps or structs with `Name` and `Value` fields?  A little Go code where you define these structures or do something with them would still make the question clearer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the shortest way to simply sort an array of structs by (arbitrary) field names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999735/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-simply-sort-an-array-of-structs-by-arbitrary-field)

Answer (score 7):

Your data looks like it could be easily represented as a slice of maps of type `map[string]int`.  Since you didn't provide any Go code in your question, I cannot be sure of the data types, so I will assume it is a slice of maps of type `map[string]int` in this answer.

A simple way to sort a slice of maps is to use [the `sort.Slice` function](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Slice).  From [a comment in the first example](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#example_) in the `sort` package documentation:

> use `sort.Slice` with a custom Less function, which can be provided as a closure. In this case no methods are needed

The Less function needs to satisfy the signature

```
func(i, j int) bool
```

Per [package documentation (at Interface)](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface):

> Less reports whether the element with index `i` should sort before the element with index `j`.

Using a closure allows you to reference your data structure in the function body even though it is not part of the parameter list.

Here's a runnable example that sorts a slice of `map[string]int` values matching the data in your question:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    in := []map[string]int{
        {
          "A": 100,
          "B": 60,
          "C": 170,
          "D": 120,
        },
        {
          "A": 64,
          "B": 90,
          "C": 52,
          "D": 98,
        },
        {
          "A": 154,
          "B": 190,
          "C": 179,
          "D": 67,
        },
    }
    for k, _ := range in[0] {
        sort.Slice(in, func(i, j int) bool { return in[i][k] < in[j][k] })
        fmt.Printf("By %s: %v\n", k, in)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
By A: [map[A:64 B:90 C:52 D:98] map[A:100 B:60 C:170 D:120] map[A:154 B:190 C:179 D:67]]
By B: [map[A:100 B:60 C:170 D:120] map[B:90 C:52 D:98 A:64] map[C:179 D:67 A:154 B:190]]
By C: [map[A:64 B:90 C:52 D:98] map[A:100 B:60 C:170 D:120] map[A:154 B:190 C:179 D:67]]
By D: [map[A:154 B:190 C:179 D:67] map[B:90 C:52 D:98 A:64] map[A:100 B:60 C:170 D:120]]
```