# A flexible and elegant way to sort slices of struct in Go

Tags: go

Let us say that we have a fairly complicated `struct` with numerous fields, that I need to sort in several places according to different criteria, e.g.

```
type MySuperType struct {
    x0, x1, x2, x3 xType
    // possibly even more fields
}
// sort 1: ascending x0, then descending x1, then more stuff
// sort 2: if x4==0 then applyCriteria2a else applyCriteria2b

func f1(mySuperSlice []MySuperType) {
    // sort 'myList' according sort #1
    // do something with the sorted list
}
func f2(mySuperSlice []MySuperType) {
    // sort 'myList' according sort #2
    // do something with the sorted list
}
func f3(mySuperSlice []MySuperType) {
    // sort 'myList' according sort #1, note: we use sort #1 again!
    // do something with the sorted list
}
```

**Proposed solution 1:**
Create a new type (alias of `[]MySuperType`) that implements `sort.Interface` for each sorting criteria required.
Problems:
(i) there is some duplicated code, as the functions `Len` and `Swap` are going to be identical
(ii) there is going to be a bunch of new types lying around that do not help with the overall readability of the program --- these new types don't really represent anything, plus the only thing that really matters is the `Less` function.

**Proposed solution 2:**
Use `sort.Slice`
It would be the perfect solution (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42872183/3923424)), but from my understanding, the sorting function has to be specified inline (I get an error `invalid receiver type []T ([]T is an unnamed type)` when I tried to define it elsewhere, which means that I need to define an alias for `[]T` and we are back to solution 1).
Now, the problem with defining the function inline is that (i) given the complexity of `MySuperType`, the function can be very long and (ii) the functions are going to be duplicated in several place (e.g. in `f1` and `f3` in my example above) -- much more annoying that in solution 1 as the sorting functions can be long and complex.
<sub>Note: (i) would not be that much of an issue if we did not have (ii) actually</sub>

**Question:**
Given my current understanding and knowledge of Go, I would use solution 1.
But does anyone knows a different approach that elegantly solves this problem or suggestions to improve the drawbacks listed above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ThunderCat's solution will work. Another option would be to write functions that return **closures** over the slice that match the signature for the `less` argument of `sort.Slice`:

```
func ascX0DescX1(s []MySuperType) (func(int, int) bool) {
    return func(i, j int) bool {
        if s[i].x0 == s[j].x0 {
            return s[i].x1 > s[j].x1
        }
        return s[i].x0 < s[j].x0
    }
}
```

Then pass that as the `less` arg to `sort.Slice`:

```
sort.Slice(mySuperSlice, ascX0DescX1(mySuperSlice))
```

Comment: This is very nice! Hurray for functional programming.

Comment: One nice thing about this method is you can reuse the functions to generate `less` arguments for other functions in the `sort` package, like `SliceIsSorted`.

Answer (score 3):

Write sort a sort function for each ordering and call from f1, f2 and f3 as appropriate:

```
func sortByX0AscX1Desc(s []MySuperType) {
    sort.Slice(s, func(i, j int) bool {
        switch {
        case s[i].x0 < s[j].x0:
            return true
        case s[i].x0 > s[j].x0:
            return false
        case s[i].x1 > s[j].x1:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    })
}

func f1(mySuperSlice []MySuperType) {
    sortByX0AscX1Desc(mySuperSlice)
    // do something with the sorted list
}
func f2(mySuperSlice []MySuperType) {
    sortBySomethingElse(mySuperSlice)
    // do something with the sorted list
}
func f3(mySuperSlice []MySuperType) {
    sortByX0AscX1Desc(mySuperSlice)
    // do something with the sorted list
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (although I feel really stupid now). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also omit the extra function and call sort where you need it.

```
type MySuperType struct {
    x0, x1, x2, x3 string
}

func f1() {
    fields := []MySuperType {
        { "a1", "b4", "c3", "d2" },
        { "a2", "b1", "c2", "d3" },
        { "a3", "b1", "c4", "d1" },
        { "a4", "b3", "c1", "d4" },
    }
    sort.SliceStable(fields, func(i, j int) bool {
        return fields[i].x1 < fields[j].x1 || fields[i].x2 > fields[j].x2
    })
    fmt.Println("by x1, then x2: ", fields)
}
```

Result: 
by x1, then x2:  [{a3 b1 c4 d1} {a2 b1 c2 d3} {a4 b3 c1 d4} {a1 b4 c3 d2}]