# Is it possible to sort a slice of structs by time in Golang?

Tags: slice

I am trying to sort the structs `Session` in the slice `Session` by each `Session`'s start time and `hall_id`. Here is the code:

```
Sessions := []Session{
    Session{
        name:      "superman",
        hall_id:   1,
        startTime: time.Date(2022, time.August, 15, 17, 35, 0, 0, time.UTC),
        endTime:   time.Date(2022, time.August, 15, 18, 35, 0, 0, time.UTC),
    },
    Session{
        name:      "thor",
        hall_id:   2,
        startTime: time.Date(2022, time.August, 15, 16, 30, 0, 0, time.UTC),
        endTime:   time.Date(2022, time.August, 15, 17, 30, 0, 0, time.UTC),
    },
    Session{
        name:      "joker",
        hall_id:   3,
        startTime: time.Date(2022, time.August, 15, 19, 40, 0, 0, time.UTC),
        endTime:   time.Date(2022, time.August, 15, 20, 30, 0, 0, time.UTC),
    },
    Session{
        name:      "batman",
        hall_id:   1,
        startTime: time.Date(2022, time.August, 15, 17, 40, 0, 0, time.UTC),
        endTime:   time.Date(2022, time.August, 15, 18, 20, 0, 0, time.UTC),
    },
}
```

The point is that I am using "time" package, and in order to create a date, you need to use Date() function, which requires multiple stuff like: year int, month, day int, hour int, minute int, etc.

I have tried the [AndreKR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999735/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-simply-sort-an-array-of-structs-by-arbitrary-field)'s answer which is:

```
slice.Sort(planets[:], func(i, j int) bool {
return planets[i].Axis < planets[j].Axis
```

})

but it seems that it does not work with multiple "parameters" of a struct. I tried this:

```
sort.Slice(Sessions[:], func(i, j int) bool {
    return Sessions[i].startTime.Year() < Sessions[j].startTime.Year(),
        int(Sessions[i].startTime.Month()) < int(Sessions[j].startTime.Month()),
        Sessions[i].startTime.Day() < Sessions[j].startTime.Day(),
        Sessions[i].startTime.Hour() < Sessions[j].startTime.Hour(),
        Sessions[i].startTime.Minute() < Sessions[j].startTime.Minute()
})
```

I am new to the Golang, so if I have made an obvious mistake I am sorry ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have got the answer:

```
sort.Slice(Sessions[:], func(i, j int) bool {
    return Sessions[i].startTime.Before(Sessions[j].startTime)
})
```

this code will solve this problem